# Akka mailbox configuration exception

Tags: java, configuration, akka, actor

When I am following the Akka document to configure a priority-mailbox in an Akka actor, it throws an exception saying that the mailbox is not configured.

The hard part is that this one works sometimes but once I changed something totally not related to this(just comments and logs) and then repackage it, it might throw the exception. And that might be fixed by another repackaging and deployment.

Here is my application.conf:

akka {

```
 prio-mailbox {
   mailbox-type = "com.ea.tnt.pn.akka.actor.mailbox.AkkaPriorityMailBox"
   //Other mailbox configuration goes here
   }
   // other stuff
   }
```

}

Mailbox:

public class AkkaPriorityMailBox extends UnboundedPriorityMailbox {

```
public AkkaPriorityMailBox(ActorSystem.Settings settings, Config config) {
    // Create a new PriorityGenerator, lower priority means more important
    super(new PriorityGenerator() {
        @Override
        public int gen(Object message) {
            //comparing algorithm
        }
    });
}

@Override
public Comparator<Envelope> cmp() {
    return new Comparator<Envelope>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Envelope t1, Envelope t2) {
            //comparing algorithm
        }
    };
}

@Override
public int initialCapacity() {
    return 10;
}
```

}

Actor creation:

```
 Props PPActorProps = Props.create(PPActor.class).withMailbox("akka.prio-mailbox");

 ActorRef actor = getContext().actorOf(PPActorProps, "actor-name-" + i);
```

The exception:

akka.ConfigurationException: configuration problem while creating XXXactor with dispatcher [akka.actor.default-dispatcher] and mailbox [akka.prio-mailbox]

Caused by: akka.ConfigurationException: Mailbox Type [akka.prio-mailbox] not configured
        at akka.dispatch.Mailboxes.lookupConfigurator(Mailboxes.scala:189) ~[pn-backend.jar:na]
        at akka.dispatch.Mailboxes.lookup(Mailboxes.scala:78) ~[pn-backend.jar:na]
        at akka.dispatch.Mailboxes.getMailboxType(Mailboxes.scala:154) ~[pn-backend.jar:na]
        at akka.actor.LocalActorRefProvider.actorOf(ActorRefProvider.scala:717) ~[pn-backend.jar:na]
        ... 16 common frames omitted